# Creating custom maps over Google Maps is possible nowadays?

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay

A few years ago we wanted to add a custom map over Google Maps (like the World looks like Midearth), but back then it was not possible. Now, I can see multiple apps that have their own overlay over Google Maps.

I tried creating my own map via Google Maps using [their suggestions](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3045850?hl=en), but this was only for pins and routes.

What I need is to have the real cities on the map (like Rome, London, Paris), but with my own custom graphics for everything (map tiles, pins, etc.).

What document shall I read for this? I am sure I missed something on Google Maps.

Comment: I'm wondering could it be http://mapbox.com these apps use instead?

Comment: @harism Hm, you may be right. Is there a way I know that they are using MapBox? Because I am sure I saw Google stamp on the bottom left. Also, does mapbox allow inserting custom maps or they simply have hundreds of predefined maps and only them can be used?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not too familiar with MapBox. But I checked their map editor once and I believe one can make rather much with it to adjust the map looks.

Comment: @harism Actually, just confirmed that I see Google logo on the bottom of these custom maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! It is possible with Google Map V2. You should consider using [TileOverlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/tileoverlay).

Essentially, every time GoogleMap wants to draw tile for specific coordinate - it asks you to provide this tile. You can use either static tile (see [TileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/TileProvider.html)) or you can provide URL, so GoogleMap goes to your web server and downloads this tile automatically (see [UrlTileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/UrlTileProvider.html))

Comment: Thanks, you are right. However, it seems to be a lot of work for the designer having to design a hundreds of tiles. Do you think that MapBox may be a better solution from designer's perspective? Of course, if you have used it before.

Comment: I haven't used it before, but as I can see, designers still have to prepare lots of images for different zoom levels. MapBox doesn't know anything about your custom map. Isn't it? MapBox just provides you an easy solution for storing your map tiles on a server, so you don't have to store huge set of tiles locally on a device

Comment: @sandalone You can find implementations of `TileProvider` that can get tiles from WMS servers or other existing online sources.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is [GroundOverlay](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/GroundOverlay.html) which can be any bitmap image that will be displayed on top of the basemap. You can even control the translucency of your map.

You most likely want to have your map image oriented north up and be scaled according to Mercator projection if the scale of your map is large enough to include Rome, London, and Paris. But if your map covers a smaller area, you don't need to worry about Mercator projection.

Comment: It is not for the whole world, but thanks for suggestions. Docs say: `Ground overlays are useful when you wish to fix a single image at one area on the map. If you want to add extensive imagery that covers a large portion of the map, you should consider a Tile overlay.`